# Fortran Error compilation when I would like to change work directory

Tags: fortran

In a Fortran subroutine I would like to change the work directory and I use

```
CHDIR("/new/work/directory")
```

but I have a compilation error

```
error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ( % [ . = =>
       [cc]       CHDIR("/new/work/directory")
       [cc] ------------------------^
```

I use CHDIR in other part of my code and I have not problems.

Someone can help me.

Comment: Are you using a `chdir` function or subroutine, or some non-standard statement?

Comment: No I do not use chdir function or subroutine. CHDIR is a standard Fortran function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CHDIR` does not exist in standard Fortran.

Compilers may provided as an extension either as a subroutine:

```
call CHDIR(...)
```

(note the `call`), or as a function

```
IER = CHDIR(...)
```

Consult your compiler's manual for the right form. E.g., [the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CHDIR.html). You may also need to use some module.

You cannot use it as a statement without anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with code below

```
INTEGER I

I = CHDIR("/new/work/directory")
```